# Motivation and intuition of double cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In Dummit and Foote, there was a problem on double cosets. Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ and $x\in G$, $HxK$ is the double coset of $x$. I can prove the double cosets partitions $G$. However, I could not see any intuition or motivation of this gear. I can understand it as a mapping $H:\frac{G}{K}\to gK$ or $K:Hx\to Hy$ where $y$ may be different from $x$. Is there anything deep for this motivation other than the mapping itself?

Comment: Double cosets may also arise in algebraic number theory, as explained in Neukirch's _Algebraic number theory_, chap. 1, §9, p. 55. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39652).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double coset arises in representation theory of finite groups, in particular [Mackey's Decomposition Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Mackey_decomposition) (a very important and useful result!).

Comment: I think Mackey's theorem on intertwining operators among induced representations, and generalizations by Bruhat, Harish-Chandra, and others, is by far the most important way that double cosets arise, and is irresistible.

Answer (score 6):

The transitive $G$-sets are precisely those isomorphic to the coset space $G/H$ for some subgroup $H\le G$. Any of our $G$-sets decomposes as a disjoint union of orbits. So we should be able to decompose $G/H\times G/K$ into orbits. Indeed we have the decomposition

$$G/H\times G/K\cong\bigsqcup_{HxK}\frac{G}{H\cap {}^xK} \tag{$\circ$}$$

as $HxK$ ranges over all double cosets. (While the expression $H\cap{}^xK$ may be asymmetrical, we know that it's conjugate by $x$ to $H^x\cap K$, and $G/A\cong G/B$ if $A\sim B$ are conjugate.)

This would be useful for finding the **structure constants** of the Burnside rings. As all finite $G$-sets are disjoint unions of orbits, we can think of them as $\Bbb N$-linear sums of orbits, and then generalize to formal $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations of orbits. We can then extend the direct product operation, originally only defined for $\Bbb N$-linear combinations, to all these formal linear combinations and this creates a multiplication operation. This (in general we call this a **Grothendieck construction**) is how we form the **Burnside ring**.

There is an analogous situation with the *complex linear representations* of the group. All finite-dimensional representations decompose as direct sums of irreducible representations. We have direct sum and tensor product operations, and when we allow formal $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations of irreducible representations we get the **Green ring**, also known as the **representation ring**.

In quantum physics and Lie algebra theory, these structure constants are called **Clebsch-Gordan coefficients**. While in the context of combinatorics, symmetric polynomials and the representation theory of the symmetric group (all inextricably linked), the structure constants of ${\rm Rep}(G)$ with $G=S_n$ a symmetric group are called the **Littlewood-Richardson coefficients**. So we see that the structure constants of the Burnside ring are at least *analogous* to some pretty important invariants in advanced mathematics, and double cosets are related to them by $(\circ)$.

(It's also possible that my answer is a bit ... reaching.)

Answer (score 4):

Double cosets can be used to describe the subgroups of free products and free products with amalgamation (which are important structures in the theory of infinite groups. See the paper *The subgroups of a free product of two groups with an amalgamated subgroup* by Karrass and Solitar (1970). The description of the subgroups of a free product with amalgamation proven by Karrass and Solitar is as follows (restricting to free products, this is more complete than, and implies, the Kurosh subgroup theorem).

**Theorem:** Let $G = A \ast_U B$ be a free product with amalgamation. The structure of a
subgroup $H$ may be described as follows: there exist double coset representative systems $\{D_{\alpha}\}$, $\{D_{\beta}\}$ for $G \mod (H, A)$ and $G \mod (H, B)$ respectively,
and there exists a set of elements $t_1, t_2,\ldots$ (possibly empty) such that

1. $H=\langle t_1 t_2,\ldots, D_{\alpha}AD_{\alpha}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots, D_{\beta}AD_{\beta}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots\rangle$;
2. $t_1, t_2,\ldots$ freely generate a free group $F$;
3. $D_{\alpha}AD_{\alpha}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots, D_{\beta}AD_{\beta}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots$ generate a generalised free product $S$ with amalgamated subgroups $D_{\alpha}UD_{\alpha}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots, D_{\beta}UD_{\beta}^{-1} \cap H,\ldots$; and
4. $H$ is the free product of the groups $T_i=\langle t_i, S\rangle$ with the subgroups $S$ amalgamated.